# Front fork preloader is not stopping to spin in any directions!

Tags: suspension

My front suspension has a preloader in the left side and lockout in the right side. The preloader was hard to spin so I applied a little bit of force to it while riding the bike. Now its free but there is no end to the adjustment in both sides. The preloader knob is not detached but it isnt working. Can someone please help regarding this above issue?

Brand is "Zoom suspension 100mm with lockout"

Comment: Does your fork have a brand and model?  Sounds like this is going to need a teardown and a service, which will need a service kit, likely new oil, all of which could vary depending on what brand and model of fork it is.

Comment: Zoom suspension 100mm with lockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the brand, this is a chinese fork for a 26" wheel.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32468783598.html

There will likely not be a rebuild kit available for it, nor any parts assembly diagrammes.

Your two options are

1. Buy a new fork, or
2. Tear into the old fork, see what you see, and if it is not fixable then buy a new fork.
3. Ride it as-is with no preload adjustment.

Sorry, that is my opinion.  Consider buying a decent used bike locally for cheap, as a parts source.  Good luck!

Comment: Zoom is a pretty standard OEM fork brand. They come on low entry level and kids bikes, even those made by decent brands. Purchasing a new fork may be difficult, finding a straight steerer, 26", QR fork  that possibly also still has brake bosses will be like finding hen's teeth. Best bet, as Criggie said, is to keep an eye out for something 2nd hand if you are unwilling to consider options 1 or 2.